# How to make sure every turtles do not overlap when follow leader in flocking behavior rule in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

i try to add leader rule in flocking behavior with below scenario:
in one room consists 2 type of turtles (leader and follower), during normal situation all turtles will wandering inside the room, however when emergency occurs, turtles will follow flocking behavior (separate, align, cohere) with consider the leader rule. if they find nearby leader, they will flock toward leader's heading and at the same time each turtles must keep certain distance to each other. thanks for the help.

```
turtles-own 
[
flockmates         
nearest-neighbor  
]

breed [type1s type1]
breed [type2s type2]

globals
[time-to-evacuate]

to setup
__clear-all-and-reset-ticks

create-type1s  (population) 
 [set color white  
  set size 0.6 
  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = blue]]

create-type2s ((percent_of_leader / 100) * population ) 
[ set color black 
  set size 0.6 
  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = blue]]  
end

to go
ask turtles [wander fd 0.1]

if emergency? = true [move]
end

to wander
[ do something]
end

to move
set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1
ask type1s [ flock]
ask type1s [ follow-leader ]
ask type1s [avoid-obstacles]
ask type1s [evacuate1]
ask type1s [ fd speed ]

ask type2s [ fd leader-speed ]
ask type2s [avoid-obstacles]
ask type2s [evacuate2]

ask turtles with [pcolor = red][die]
if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]  
[ stop ]
tick
end

to evacuate1
let beings-seen patches in-cone vision vision-angle with [pcolor = red] 
  if any? beings-seen 
  [ let target one-of beings-seen
    face target]
end  

to evacuate2
let beings-seen patches in-cone leader-vision leader-vision-angle with [pcolor = red] 
  if any? beings-seen 
  [ let target one-of beings-seen
    face target]
 end

to flock  ;; turtle procedure
find-flockmates
if any? flockmates
[ find-nearest-neighbor
  ifelse distance nearest-neighbor < minimum-separation
    [ separate ]
    [ if any? flockmates
      [align
      cohere ] ] ]
end

to find-flockmates  ;; turtle procedure
set flockmates other breed in-cone vision vision-angle
end

to find-nearest-neighbor ;; turtle procedure
set nearest-neighbor min-one-of flockmates [distance myself]
end

to follow-leader
let leaders type2s in-cone vision vision-angle
if any? leaders
[ let any-leader min-one-of leaders [distance myself]
face min-one-of leaders [distance myself ]
let observed-heading ([towards myself + 180] of any-leader)
turn-away observed-heading max-avoid-turn ]
end

to separate  ;; turtle procedure
 let observed-heading ([heading] of nearest-neighbor)
 turn-away observed-heading max-separate-turn
end

to align  ;; turtle procedure
 turn-towards average-flockmate-heading max-align-turn
end

to-report average-flockmate-heading  ;; turtle procedure
 let x-component sum [sin heading] of flockmates
 let y-component sum [cos heading] of flockmates
 ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
 [ report heading ]
 [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end

to cohere  ;; turtle procedure
 turn-towards average-heading-towards-flockmates max-cohere-turn
end

to-report average-heading-towards-flockmates  ;; turtle procedure
 let x-component mean [sin (towards myself + 180)] of flockmates
 let y-component mean [cos (towards myself + 180)] of flockmates
 ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
  [ report heading ]
  [ report atan x-component y-component ]
 end

to turn-towards [new-heading max-turn]  ;; turtle procedure
 turn-at-most (subtract-headings new-heading heading) max-turn
end

to turn-away [new-heading max-turn]  ;; turtle procedure
 turn-at-most (subtract-headings heading new-heading) max-turn
end

to turn-at-most [turn max-turn]  ;; turtle procedure
 ifelse abs turn > max-turn
[ ifelse turn > 0
    [ rt max-turn ]
    [ lt max-turn ] ]
[ rt turn ]
end

to avoid-obstacles
 if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green
 [lt random-float 360] 
end
```

Comment: Juliana, this isn't the kind of question that's usually considered appropriate for Stackoverflow.  Stackoverflow is designed for questions in which there is a specific problem--usually with a piece of code--that can be given a specific, concrete answer.  By contrast, it sounds as if you're asking for help with the overall design of your program, starting from nothing more than a description of what you are trying to do.  It would be better if you could try to write part of the program, and then ask for help about specific aspects of it.

Comment: thanks @Mars for the feedback. i should ask the other way round. attached is my code for leader rule in flocking behavior. the problem now, how to ensure each turtles follow the same leader also have certain distance between them. so they will not overlap. I've tried to look at some example in the library, but not managed to find an answer. thanks.